# How to create object dynamically

Tags: javascript

I am new in Javascript. I want to create array of dynamic object. Here for example

I have an array of constructor in which I am getting some value. In my constructor MyItms have some attributes like value and property. I want to make an object by assigning or mapping to property

```
var Item = MyItems;
    for(var i=0; i<MyItems.length; i++){
            var Values = MyItems[i]._value; // Car is my value here
            var prop =     MyItems[i]._property; // Name
                var obj ={
                    prop : Values
                };
    }
```

But In this case obj is returning value like

```
`prop : car`,
```

What I am expecting here is 
    Name : Car

Also I want array of objects for all `MyItems` Any way to get this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In newer JS, you can write this (note the square brackets):

```
var obj = {
    [prop]: Values
};
```

In older JS this is not available, you would need to do this (still works in new JS as well):

```
var obj = {};
obj[prop] = Values;
```

If you want an array of objects as a result, you can initialise an empty array at top:

```
var objs = [];
```

and then push each `obj` into it:

```
objs.push(obj);
```

Alternately, and more readably, you can use the `map` function:

```
var objs = MyItems.map(function(item) {
  ...
  return resultObj;
});
```